# Bootstrap tab-panels not having active class removed, but only sometimes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with bootstraps tabs and tabpanels not working with the active class as intended. I know there are many questions about this, but in all the ones I have read, adding and removing the inactive class is not working at all. In my case, it works... but kind of. First I'll provide the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills hr-divider-content hr-divider-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#a-tab" aria-expanded="false">A</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#b-tab" aria-expanded="true">B</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#c-tab" aria-expanded="false">C</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="a-tab" class="tab-pane highlight active" aria-expanded="true">

    </div>
    <div id="b-tab" class="tab-pane highlight" aria-expanded="false">

    </div>
    <div id="c-tab" class="tab-pane highlight" aria-expanded="false">

    </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript comes from just including all the bootstrap 4 stuff.

So here's the thing, it starts off with some issues, being that as you click between the 3 tabs it will usually show 2 of them, but after clicking around for about 10 seconds it seems to fix itself and work completely as intended, showing only the content for the currently selected tab. I also use the same exact code with different names in other locations on my site, and it works perfectly fine.

Does anyone have any intuition into what would be causing the content to show incorrectly only the first 10 or so times clicking through the tabs, but then it works perfectly well until the page is refreshed?

Answer (score 1):

I think there was a bug in the initial Bootstrap 4 code. I was using Bootstrap 4.0.0 beta when I encountered this issue. I downloaded [Bootstrap version 4.1.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/) and now the active class gets removed from the tab-pane as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to apply active class properly.You have given active class to a link but it should be into li.nav-item and also in your nav items you have given your active class to #b-tab and in below given active class to a-tab content. Look at updated HTML code

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills hr-divider-content hr-divider-nav">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#a-tab" aria-expanded="false">A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#b-tab" aria-expanded="true">B</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#c-tab" aria-expanded="false">C</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="a-tab" class="tab-pane highlight active" aria-expanded="true">
    a-tab content
  </div>
  <div id="b-tab" class="tab-pane highlight" aria-expanded="false">
    b-tab content
  </div>
  <div id="c-tab" class="tab-pane highlight" aria-expanded="false">
    c-tab content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to the [bootstrap 4.1 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#tabs) the 'active' class should be applied to the nav-link and not the nav-item.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-link.active', function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        $(".nav-link").removeClass('active');
        $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.tab-pane[id="' + href + '"]').addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: Custom scripting is not needed with core functionality of a library.